# Issues with Proportional Editing and X-Axis Mirror in Blender

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, mirror, axis

[image]

[image]

Hello Blender Community,

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with proportional editing and X-axis mirroring in Blender. When I enable X-axis mirroring (not the mirror modifier, but the X-axis mirror option for editing), the transformations on one side of my model cause unexpected distortions on the mirrored side. However, when I disable the X-axis mirror, I can edit the mesh normally without any mirrored distortions.

Issue Description: With X-axis mirroring enabled during proportional editing, the mirrored side seems to warp or distort in an unusual way.

Troubleshooting Done:

The topology of the mesh appears to be symmetrical.
No other modifiers are causing conflicts.
All transformations have been applied to the object.
The mesh is correctly aligned with the global axes.
The origin was initially at the geometric center, and editing worked fine, but after moving the origin to the center of mass, the X-axis mirror stopped functioning correctly.
Additional Concern: The issue with proportional editing and X-axis mirroring began after I tried adjusting the origin point to what I believed was the center mass of the mesh. Before adjusting the origin, the mirroring worked, albeit with some distortions.

if i turn off the x-axis mirror and move the left check up it works fine as well.

Thank you for any suggestions or guidance you can provide!

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (delete a part of the face if you don't want to share the whole thing)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i just shared it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh is not really symmetrical (for example the one I highlight won't move its opposite), to fix that select the first shapekey (*Basis*), go into *Mesh > Symmetrize* and you are good.

[image]

Comment: wow thanks a lot! you the man!!!!

Comment: just finding this out now but after i Symmetrize my mesh the bones stop working like there not attached to the mesh any more do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot that, so what you should do instead of a Symmetrize is cut off half of your mesh (lef or right half), give it a Mirror modifier (at the top of the modifiers stack), apply the Mirror modifier